# Which type of qorban did the Pesach offering most closely resemble?

Tags: passover, korban, shemot-exodus

The Pesach story takes place prior to the establishment of the Mishkan and Bet Hamikdash. Since the Israelites had not been commanded to perform the various offerings until the giving of the Torah, which type of qorban did the Pesach offering most closely fall under?

• Olah
• Zebach Sh'lamim
• Chatat
• Minchah
• Asham
• other?

Obviously it was not the parah adumah.

Comment: It was a _Korban Pesach_ type. (This seems obvious, so maybe I just don't understand what you seek.)

Comment: There are a number of other examples of offerings before the Mishkan was built (Gen 8:20, 22:13, 31:54, 46:1)

Comment: I guess I'm asking which qorban it most closely resembled after the Levitical qorbanot were commanded. It obviously was not a guilt offering so it would not be considered an asham. More close to a peace offering? See where I'm going with this?

Comment: That's not a very well defined question. It could be similar in some ways to some offerings and similar to others in other ways. Your question asks for "exact type". Maybe [edit] your post to better clarify what you seek.

Comment: Good edit, @Ephraim, but I think Double AA is right- it's its own type of unique offering

Comment: @JoshK we can group Korbanot into categories in many ways. I think grouping Pesach with Shelamim is quite natural actually. But it's hard to say that categorization is particularly objective or that it is obviously the best way to categorize them. (Rambam for instance splits offerings into four categories: Olah, Chatat, Shelamim, Mincha. I could also categorize them as Animal, Bird and Grain. Or Public and Private.) In short I disagree with you that there can't be categorization but I also don't see any way this question is answerable as is.

Comment: @DoubleAA. If I'm not mistaken, you actually answered the question quite clearly. It does not resemble any other qorban. It is its own. Thank you.

Comment: You are mistaken. It does resemble other Korbanot [in certain ways]. If it resembled something else in all ways it would be identical! Different similarities will be relevant in different contexts, so it's hard to say which ones it "most closely resemble"

Comment: Understood, thank you.